# When I generate a PDF, text is working but image is not showing. How can I solve this?

Tags: codeigniter

When I generate a PDF, the text is working but the image is not showing an image. How can I solve this? How can I use an image in my PDF? In the below I have given some code of my problem.

This is the view code: all of the code is included in one field in the database.

**view code :**

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="sixweekletterwithauto" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="sixweekletterwithauto-tab">
                             <form  action="patient/addcaseHistory" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <center>
                                  <h2 style="margin-top: 0;color:#55518a">Case Notes</h2>
                                  <textarea name="editor1" class="ckeditor">
                                    <img src="../uploads/pic.jpg" width="1000px" height="200px">

                                      <p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</p>

                                      <table align="right" style="width:200px">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;Dr M Takla</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;621 Boronia Rd Wantirna South</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;VIC 3152</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;Ph 97380009 Fax</td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                     </table>
                                      <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                      <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                      <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                      <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                      <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                      <p>Dear Dr M Takla,,</p>
                                      <p><strong>Re: Aryan Karat (DOB : 9/12/2008)</strong></p>
                                      <p>Thank you for referring Aryan Karat, for assistance with &ldquo;behaviour problems, hyperactivity and phobias&rdquo;.</p>

                                      <p>The therapeutic process with Aryan has focussed on reducing anxiety and improving self confidence and self esteem. I have worked on a number of cognitive and behavioural strategies to assist Aryan in managing his worry. His teacher and parents have reported some positive changes, however they continue to be concerned about his constant need for reassurance by adults and anxiety in some situations.</p>

                                      <p>Further sessions with Aryan are recommended in order to ensure that the skills and strategies imparted can be reinforced and fully assimilated.</p>
                                      <p>If you wish to discuss this matter further, I may be contacted at 0419 489 333.</p>
                                      <p>Thank you again for your referral, and I look forward to your reply.</p>
                                      <p>Yours Sincerely</p>
                                      <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                      <p>Ms Angela Delle-Vergini,<br />
                                      Psychologist<br />
                                      M.A.P.S (B.A, Grad Dip Psych, M.Psych (Counselling).</p>
                                      <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                  </textarea>
                                  <script>
                                          CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2' );
                                          CKEDITOR.add
                                  </script>
                                </center>
                                <input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value='<?php echo $patient->id; ?>'>
                                  <input type="hidden" name="date" value='<?php echo date('m-d-Y') ?>'>
                                <div style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                                  <button class="btn btn-blue">Save & Finalise</button>
                                </div>
                              </form>
                          </div>
```

**controller code :**

```
function addcaseHistory() {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $patient_id = $this->input->post('patient_id');

        $date = $this->input->post('date');
        $description = $this->input->post('editor1');

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
        $redirect = $this->input->post('redirect');
        if (empty($redirect)) {
            $redirect = 'patient/medicalHistory?id=' . $patient_id;
        }

        // Validating Name Field
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'Date', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[100]|xss_clean');
        // Validating Password Field

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('editor1', 'Description', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[10000]|xss_clean');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            if (!empty($id)) {
                redirect("patient/editMedicalHistory?id=$id");
            } else {
                $this->load->view('home/dashboard'); // just the header file
                $this->load->view('add_new');
                $this->load->view('home/footer'); // just the header file
            }
        } else {

            if (!empty($patient_id)) {
                $patient_details = $this->patient_model->getPatientById($patient_id);
                $patient_name = $patient_details->name;
                $patient_phone = $patient_details->phone;
                $patient_address = $patient_details->address;
            } else {
                $patient_name = 0;
                $patient_phone = 0;
                $patient_address = 0;
            }
            //$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $data = array();
            $data = array(
                'patient_id' => $patient_id,
                'date' => $date,
                'description' => $description,
                'patient_name' => $patient_name,
                'patient_phone' => $patient_phone,
                'patient_address' => $patient_address,
            ); 

            if (empty($id)) {     // Adding New department
                $this->patient_model->insertMedicalHistory($data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', 'Added');
            } else { // Updating department
                $this->patient_model->updateMedicalHistory($id, $data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', 'Updated');
            }
            // Loading View
            $data['settings'] = $this->settings_model->getSettings();
         $this->load->view('home/dashboard2',$data); // just the header file
        $this->load->view('medical_history', $data);
        $this->load->view('home/footer'); // just the footer file
        }
    }

public function pdfdetails()
     {
      $id = $this->input->get('id');


       $html_content .= $this->patient_model->getMedicalHistoryByPatientId2($id);


       $this->pdf->loadHtml($html_content);
       $this->pdf->render();
       $this->pdf->stream("".$id.".pdf", array("Attachment"=>0));    
     }
```

**Model code:**

```
function getMedicalHistoryByPatientId2($id)
 {
  $this->db->where('id', $id);
  $data = $this->db->get('medical_history');

  foreach($data->result() as $row)
  {
   $output .= '<p>'."<img src='../uploads/'".$row->img_url."/>".$row->description.'</p>';
  }

  return $output;
 }
```

Comment: start by removing the non-pertinent code, and telling us what pdf library you are using (there are many third-party resource for CI).

Comment: using dompdf libaray

Comment: Improved grammar and formatting